# how to login as admin in magento without commenting domain,secure and httponly

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.4

when I without commenting these 3 lines of code it's not login as admin.
if I comment those 3 lines it's login.

Varien.php

```
// session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
        /*
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        */
    );
```

So what is the use of it? 
why it's acting like this?
If I Login as admin without commenting those 3 lines what should I do?

thanks in advance.............

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you install magento on localhost.. if that is the case, then use as base url 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Modify in `core_config_data` table all occurrences of `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and clear the cache.
If you are not on localhost, make sure the domain name matches your base url.

Comment: hi marius, where is this file core_config_data?

Comment: Sorry for  the misunderstanding. I should have mentioned that it's a table. I've edited my answer.

Comment: ok sorry I misunderstanding..

Comment: hi marius,127.0.0.1 value is not there in core_config_data table.

Comment: I said replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`, not the other way around.